# How do I insert my imploded array into my database?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update permissions of userroles in my application.
Everything works the way I want untill I want to insert the changes into my database.

```
    $permission = $_POST['permission'];
    $permissiondb = implode(",", $permission);

    print_r($permission)
    print_r($permissiondb);
```

The permission print shows this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 6 [4] => 5 [5] => 4 )
```

The permissiondb print shows this:

```
1,2,3,6,5,4
```

my db query is:

```
INSERT INTO give_permissions (userrole, permission_id) VALUES ($userrole, $permissions);
```

When I send the values to my database it inserts a ' 0 ' at the wanted userrole, but instead
I want the system to put in all permissions for the userrole.

I hope I gave enough code for you to help me... can someone help me with this?

Comment: what is the datatype for column permission_id in your table. I guess its Int

Comment: u can not add array directly to DB. Either add each item in one row or serialize() json_encode() the array and add at once

Comment: @rakeshjain Yes, its an INT.

Abhik Chakraborty Can you give me an example?

Comment: if it is int you can't put a string into it.

Comment: if your datatype is int and you pass it a string, what do you expect it to do. Change your datatype to VARCHAR(X) choosing X as per your requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of ids which are being stored in permission_id which suggests that its setup to take a single integer? Thus a list of ids will not work.

**a) Change your data type to varchar and wrap $permissions with '$permissions'.**

By using this method you would stick with implode(",", $permissions) but there is a better way.

```
// Your example with modifications
$permission = $_POST['permission'];
$permissiondb = implode(",", $permission);
// INSERT INTO give_permissions (userrole, permission_id) 
// VALUES ($userrole, '$permissiondb');
```

**b) Change your data type to varchar and use 'json_encode($permissions)' - This would be the preferable option by many as a shortcut.**

When you use json_encode() you store it in a more manageable way. When you encode it you will receive a string in the format of [{1},{2},...] which you can drop into your table quite nicely.

So what about later on when you want to retrieve that permissions list? You use json_decode($permissions) which will then give you a JSON array. For your purposes its easier to cast that json array to a standard array (array)json_decode($permissions) which will take that [{}] string and give you a perfectly standard array(1,2,3,...).

```
// Your example with modifications
$permission = $_POST['permission'];
$permissiondb = json_encode($permission);
// INSERT INTO give_permissions (userrole, permission_id) 
// VALUES ($userrole, '$permissiondb');
```

**c) Setup a corresponding table to take each id and link them. - This would be the perfect ideal.**

Comment: Hi Neil, 
Do i need to use json_encode instead of implode?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you use json_encode you get a json array which will allow you to later on use json_decode() and get the original array back :) I will update my answer with some more comprehensive examples to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Change permission data type `int` to `varchar` and try this

```
INSERT INTO give_permissions (userrole, permission_id) VALUES ($userrole, $permissions);
```